# Publishing the data from BAG file

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to learn ROS and filtering of point cloud.
I performed some tutorials on the same. However now I am stuck that the data from node for bag file is not getting published. Please refer to the data from `rostopic list -v`

```
Published topics:
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 4 publishers
 * /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock] 1 publisher
 * /all_velo [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] 1 publisher
 * /diagnostics [diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray] 1 publisher
 * /velodyne_points [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] 1 publisher
 * /velodyne_pointcloud_TransformNodelet/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription] 1 publisher
 * /velodyne_pointcloud_TransformNodelet/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config] 1 publisher
 * /tf_static [tf2_msgs/TFMessage] 1 publisher
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/oxts/imu [sensor_msgs/Imu] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/oxts/gps/fix [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/oxts/gps/vel [geometry_msgs/TwistStamped] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_gray_left/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_gray_left/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_gray_right/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_gray_right/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_color_left/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_color_left/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_color_right/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/camera_color_right/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo] 1 publisher
 * /kitti/velo/pointcloud [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] 1 publisher
 * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher

Subscribed topics:
 * /velodyne_points [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] 1 subscriber
 * /velodyne_packets [velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan] 1 subscriber
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
 * /statistics [rosgraph_msgs/TopicStatistics] 1 subscriber
```

I have used kitti2bag to convert to bag file.
Below the commands used by me to run the package

```
roscore
rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone velodyne_pointcloud/TransformNodelet
rosrun beginner_tutorials all_velo input:=/velodyne_points
rosbag play -l kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag
```

In rqt_graph I cannot see a topic from the node corresponding to rosbag
I believe this is why I cannot convert the pointcloud.

I am not sure where I am making mistake.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376174/publishing-the-data-from-bag-file/) by [SAM MATHEW](https://answers.ros.org/users/9041/sam-mathew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-04-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TzviH](https://answers.ros.org/users/40533/tzvih/) on 2021-04-14**:
Hi,
Can you write in a more understandable way what exactly you are trying to do?

Can you write again your steps? (e.g. "roscore" "roslaunch.." "rosbag play..")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it fixed. I was not subscribing correct topic on all_velo. After changing the
rosrun beginner_tutorials all_velo input:=/kitti/velo/pointcloud. It started working.

---

Originally posted by [SAM MATHEW](https://answers.ros.org/users/9041/sam-mathew/) with karma: 16 on 2021-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0